# auto template parameter, data member and constness

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-traits, data-member-pointers

Suppose I have a pointer to data member and I want to know if it's const or not. In other words:

```
struct S {
    const int i; // this is const
    int j;
};
```

In C++ I used to do something like this:

```
template<typename Class, typename Type, Type Class:: *>
struct is_const_data_member: std::false_type {};

template<typename Class, typename Type, const Type Class:: *Member>
struct is_const_data_member<Class, const Type, Member>: std::true_type {};

template<typename Class, typename Type, Type Class:: *Member>
void foo() {
    const auto bar = is_const_data_member<Class, Type, Member>::value;
    // ...
}
```

However, now there is the `auto` template parameter and template parameters list are much elegant:

```
template<auto Member>
void foo() {
    // ...
}
```

In this case, the solo way I found to know if the data member point to something that is const is:

```
const auto bar = std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::declval<Class>().*Member)>>;
```

However, it looks *ugly* to me and I feel like there must be a better way to do it.
Is there any other (shorter) solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

You could change `is_const_data_member` to operate on a single type template parameter:

```
template<typename MemPtr>
struct is_const_data_member: std::false_type {};

template<typename Class, typename Type>
struct is_const_data_member<const Type Class::*>: std::true_type {};
```

Then, from `template<typename Class, typename Type, Type Class:: *Member> void foo()` you use it as

```
is_const_data_member<Type Class::*>::value
```

(Which, in my opinion, is slightly more intuitive.)

And from `template<auto Member> void foo()` you use it as

```
is_const_data_member<decltype(Member)>::value
```

---

You could also rewrite the trait to operate on an `auto` template parameter. But by using a type parameter you avoid unnecessary instantinations for different pointers of same type, which is supposedly a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_const_data_member : std::false_type {};

template <typename C, typename T>
struct is_const_data_member<const T C::*> : std::true_type {};

template <auto T>
constexpr bool is_const_data_member_v = is_const_data_member<decltype(T)>::value;
```

And then, for example

```
struct Test
{
    int a;
    const int b;
};


bool x = is_const_data_member_v<&Test::a>;
bool y = is_const_data_member_v<&Test::b>;
```

[working test here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Astruct+is_const_data_member+:+std::false_type+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+C,+typename+T%3E%0Astruct+is_const_data_member%3Cconst+T+C::*%3E+:+std::true_type+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cauto+T%3E%0Aconstexpr+bool+is_const_data_member_v+%3D+is_const_data_member%3Cdecltype(T)%3E::value%3B%0A%0A%0Astruct+Test%0A%7B%0A++++int+a%3B%0A++++const+int+b%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Abool+x+%3D+is_const_data_member_v%3C%26Test::a%3E%3B%0Abool+y+%3D+is_const_data_member_v%3C%26Test::b%3E%3B%0A%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-stdlib%3Dlibc%2B%2B+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:69.7151424287856,n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:30.284857571214395,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)